# Reacquiring previous Graphics2D instance of a BufferedImage

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I create a BufferedImage in a parent class method and use Graphics2D to set options (Paint, RenderingHints, etc.). Another class inherits this base class and overrides the method but calls the superclass method to acquire the BufferedImage instance.

How do I keep the Graphics2D settings from the superclass method?

```
class Parent {
    BufferedImage draw() {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(...)
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics()

        g2.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0))

        return image;
    }   
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    BufferedImage draw() {
        BufferedImage image = super.draw()
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics()

        System.out.println(g2.getColor()) // 255, 255, 255

        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use createGraphics() instead of getGraphics(). Regarding the question - you probably need to save the created Graphics2D object in a private field in Parent.

Comment: BufferedImage does not have any references to corresponding Graphics2D, getGraphics() just calls createGraphics(), which creates a new instance on each call. So you need to save the reference to created Graphics2D manually in some private or protected field.

Comment: @Alex Sounds like a good and simple idea. Didn't know that BufferedImages do not keep references to the Graphics2D instances, that's why the attempt with the `getGraphics` method. Thanks for your help.